# Two-syllable verbs stressed on the first syllable that do not double the final consonant in the --ing form

Tags: gerunds, verb-forms, present-participles

Can anyone think of more two-syllable verbs that have stress on the first syllable and **do not double the final consonant in the -ing form**. The instances I am looking for will have a vowel before the last consonant in the infinitive form.

For example:  `open > opening` ; `enter > entering`   (in red below)

[image]

Comment: argue - arguing? /ˈɑːɡ.juː/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
answer - answering
billet - billeting
fidget - fidgeting
weather - weathering
cater - catering
meter - metering
reckon - reckoning
budget - budgeting
ratchet - ratcheting
beckon - beckoning
slander - slandering
swallow - swallowing
mention - mentioning




travel - traveling (Am.E.), travelling (Be.E.)
grovel - same as 'travel'
shovel - same as 'travel'
```